# Not able to login to docusign using apex

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

I am trying to use docusign REST API. I am trying to login to docusign but getting some error. 
Below is my code

```
public class DocuSignIntegration{

private static final string TOKEN_URL = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information';
private static final string userName = '***';
private static final string password = '***';
private static final string integrationKey = '***';

public DocuSignIntegration(){

    getToken();
}

public void  getToken(){

 String authenticationHeader = 
            '<DocuSignCredentials>' + 
                '<Username>' + userName+ '</Username>' +
                '<Password>' + password + '</Password>' + 
                '<IntegratorKey>' + integrationKey  + '</IntegratorKey>' + 
            '</DocuSignCredentials>';
 string sPostBody = '';
      Http h = new Http();
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      HttpResponse res;

      req.setEndpoint(TOKEN_URL);
      req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
      req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/xml');
      req.setHeader('X-DocuSign-Authentication',authenticationHeader );
      req.setMethod('GET');
      req.setBody(sPostBody);

      System.debug('====request===='+req);

      res = h.send(req);

      string sResp = res.getBody();    

      System.debug(sResp);

}
}
```

but i am getting the error
10:42:47.070 (70578000)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[65]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information, Method=GET]
10:42:47.265 (265984000)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[65]|System.HttpResponse[Status=The URL provided does not resolve to a resource., StatusCode=404]

Anybody have any idea why i am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: Taking a quick look I don't see anything wrong with the code, are you absolutely positive you are providing the correct `userName`, `password`, and `integratorKey` values?  (Note that the userName is your account email)  One way to confirm is to go to demo.docusign.net (not www!) and make sure you can login using your email and password.  If yes, then go to the Preferences -> API screen and make sure you have copied your Integrator Key correctly...

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this issue just delete req.setBody(sPostBody); You should not provide even an empty string for the request body.